# How to update component while form loads

Tags: vb.net

I have a form and a button. When you press the button, i want it to load my second form. On the second form is a webbrowser which loads a site.

Thing is, the second form takes a few seconds to load. So i need to implement something to tell the end user, hang on.. We are trying to load something.

The best and simple way would be to update the button clicked text value to: Loading...

I had code to change the text on the button, then load the form.. Thing is, the label would not change but would change AFTER the second form loaded! <-- I did my research and found out its cause im doing single threading?

If i place `Application.DoEvents()` after my label change then it works, but i also searched its overkill and shouldnt be used? What would be a efficient and effective way to update my label without hogging a lot of resources?

My code:

```
label1.Text = "Loading..."
Application.DoEvents() 'Without this, label only changes AFTER form completes loading
secondform.Show()
me.hide()
```

Comment: Start another thread...

Comment: `label1.Refresh`  Seems like most users would know that web sites sometimes take time to load

Comment: It is not the web site loading that is making it slow, that happens in the background.  Could be that the 2nd form is just very expensive to paint.  Check that by minimizing and restoring the window.  Could be because a browser simply is expensive to create the first time, check that by closing a recreating the 2nd form.  Using label1.Update() is a simple workaround, but if it is systemic then do consider using Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

Answer (score 1):

I think normal practice is to have an Hourglass pointer during times when a program is executing something.

Also, you can have your 'web window' load hidden (visible = false) and have it appear once the page is loaded inside the web control.

Just a thought.

Comment: If you want to use threading, you will have to invoke using delegates.